# C++ pass by reference to constructor. Will member be a full private copy?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, initializer-list

In C++ I have a constructor that accepts an object of class `descriptor`. This class has recently grown in size and I need to pass it by reference more. If I pass it by reference into the following ctor will the member still make its own copy given that it is not declared as a reference type?

```
    descriptor taskedStats;
public:
    CWorkerThread(int ticketNumber, int threadNumber, descriptor taskedStats) :
        _pPaginatableForm(pPaginatableForm), ticketNumber(ticketNumber)
        , threadNumber(threadNumber), taskedStats(taskedStats) {}
```

or

```
    descriptor taskedStats;
public:
    CWorkerThread(int ticketNumber, int threadNumber, descriptor &taskedStats) :
        _pPaginatableForm(pPaginatableForm), ticketNumber(ticketNumber)
        , threadNumber(threadNumber), taskedStats(taskedStats) {}
```

Comment: "declared as a reference type" makes it sound like you're talking about C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default, or implicit, compiler-supplied copy constructor makes shallow copies of all members and would have the following signature:

```
descriptor(const descriptor &other);
```

so passing a reference to descriptor would be no different to attempting (in C parlance) to pass a copy- they would both in fact just be passed by reference.

If the member was declared as a reference type then, just as for pointers, its type wouldn't match in the above, implicit, copy constructor and a reference assignment would be performed, thuse invalidating any attempt to create a local copy in each object.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor will make a copy, whatever. If you pass by value then you could be making 2 copies, however the compiler is likely to optimise away one of them.

Still, the better option is to accept a const reference, i.e.

```
CWorkerThread(int ticketNumber, int threadNumber, descriptor const& taskedStats) :
   _pPaginatableForm(pPaginatableForm), 
   _ticketNumber(ticketNumber), 
   _threadNumber(threadNumber), 
   _taskedStats(taskedStats) 
{}
```

Of course once we enter the world of C++11 and move constructors you won't need to make any copies at all, as long as the one being passed in is no longer needed. There are ways to do that even now, but requires special "hacking" inside the object, or use of smart-pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The class member is declared as an object, so an object it is.

The reference passed to the constructor will be used to initialise the member, using its copy constructor.

It's best to pass by `const` reference when you can; that makes it clear that the constructor won't modify the argument, and also allows you to pass a temporary value.

Comment: Just as I can `const` all applicable members thanks to the wonders of the initializer-list. This is all news to me.

Answer (score 1):

The change in parameter from `descriptor` to `descriptor&` will still result in the member variable `taskedStats` being copied (using copy constructor) from the argument `taskedStats`.

To avoid the copy you could make the member variable `taskedStats` a `descriptor&`, but this means that the argument `taskedStats` **must** be valid for the lifetime of the `CWorkerThread` object (in this case not making the argument `taskedStats` a `const descriptor&` would prevent the passing of temporary objects).